# Menu css não funciona ao entrar atráves do Google, mas funciona normalmente via URL

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo, menu

Este problema acontece em dispositivos mobile. É um tanto estranho mas quando acesso o site pela URL, o menu funciona normalmente, ou seja, ao clicar nas 3 barrinhas horizontais, o menu aparece. Mas quando vou no google, faço a pesquisa e entro no site através do google, até aparece as 3 barrinhas do menu mas não abre o menu ao clicar(tocar) nas barrinhas. Não faz nada e não aparece o menu.

Alguma idéia do problema? Muito obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou fazer um refresh após acessar via resultados do Google? Está com cara de cache isso.

Comment: Sim Thiago, foi minha primeira reação..

Comment: Bom, como vc diz que as 3 barrinhas aparecer, não deve ser CSS, e sim JavaScript. As referencias de seus JS estão no fim da página HTML? Logo antes do </html>

Comment: o meu menu e as animações dele estão inteiramente em CSS, não tem Java Script

Comment: Pode compartilhar a URL? Já viu no Developer Tools (F12) do navegador se mostra algo no tracking do Console?

Comment: Por favor, informe a url e o termo a pesquisar no google para encontra-la

Comment: Pessoal consegui.. o problema era com o z-index, na barra do cabeçalho estava por cima do menu quando abria. Ele abria por baixo. Obrigado Thiago e Alan pela disposição.

Comment: @DEB teria como postar a solução, pode ser que tenha mais pessoas com sua dúvida.